# how to use LIKE with _ in the query?

Tags: php, sql

i've a sql database with thousands of URLs. And i constantly update it without any modification in the Url using php5.

now, i'd like the add only the url which are not present in the database, i do this by check the database using this sql query

```
$q = $urlToCheck;
SELECT * FROM pligg WHERE rawUrl LIKE '$q%'
```

Here is the problem, some of the Urls which are already in the database are like

```
http://example.com/a_b_c.html
http://example.com/a1b1c.html
```

if i run the query

```
$q = 'http://example.com/a_b';
SELECT * FROM pligg WHERE rawUrl LIKE '$q%'
```

then it will return both the Urls. I want to return only the exact match Url. So, i want to get only this url

```
http://example.com/a_b_c.html
```

any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For **MySQL** you need to escape the `_`; it should be `\_`. For **MSSQL** it should be `[_]`

**EDIT**
[Here's the manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) on `_` and escaping wildcards as `%` and `_` for MySQL. You can actually specify the escape character if you like.

```
$q = 'http://example.com/a_b';
$qescaped = str_replace('_', '\_', $q);

$result = my_execute_query_function($qescaped);
```

[Here's the manual page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) for MSSQL.

```
$qescaped = str_replace('_', '[_]', $q);
```

(Also: MSSQL also allows you to specify the escape character (which I didn't know)).

Other RDBMS'es like [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html), [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions007.htm) etc. might have their own escape characters and/or ways of specifying them. Check their respective manual pages (linked for your convenience).

Comment: If it's SQL Server, I think the syntax is `[_]`, but yes. +1

Comment: And I don't see the DBMS identified anywhere here? It just says SQL? So probably worth including other options...

Comment: I was assuming MySQL because this question was tagged `php` + `sql`. The most commonly used combination is php + mysql so it seemed pretty safe to assume this. @Nok Imchen: `sql` is a "structured query language", a way to talk with a database system if you will, and some implementations (as you can see here, for example, MySQL and MSSQL) differ a little in their "dialect". So "SQL" is not a database "brand". Next time please specify the actual "brand" of the RDBMS: MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc.

Comment: Yes, most likely MySQL with PHP, I agree - but not a given. Nice thorough answer if it is... ;)

Comment: @DavidM You were correct; assumptions are the mother of all... :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Robill, may i know how mnay such characters exist? like i should escape ' and " and _ and % and what else?

Comment: @NokImchen The `'` and `"` should already be handled in your function (I hope, otherwise you're wide open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) unless you're using parameterized queries or PDO etc.). So you shouldn't need to escape them explicitly. For patterns passed to a LIKE function, AFAIK, you should only need to escape `%` and `_`. You could have figured this out yourself by reading the manual pages for your specific RDBMS. Actually; as long as you don't specify which "brand" you're using it is entirely possible you need to escape, for example, `@` for "brand" X.